# Count Multiple Items in a Cell

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a way to count how many of each item is in a list like this?

There is a system like this in my job and I would like to automate the counting of items as there can be the occasional item missed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/947q4.png)

Comment: so, if I follow, you want something that would tell you had a total of 5 black chairs?

Comment: @Alan Waage Yes. I can change how they are added so I could use a countif statement but that still doesn't count the QTY field.

Answer (score 0):

Are the chairs entered in standard manners? I see row 4 shows `BLACK Chair` and row 3 shows `2 chairs BLACK`. Are these standard ways of representing chair entries? If so, how about this for counting the black chairs.

`=IF(C2="BLACK Chair",A2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("chairs BLACK",C2,1)),VALUE(MID(C2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2&1234567890)),FIND(" ",C2,FIND(" ",C2,FIND("+",C2,1))+1)-FIND(" ",C2,FIND("+",C2,1))-1)),0))`

I hacked this together a bit so test to make sure it fits you but it seems to be working with my test set.

Then you could create separate columns for each type so maybe column D is black chairs, column E is red chairs.

For the tables, create columns and try:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Beech Table",C2)),A2,0)`

Then replicate for other table types.

I don't know how you're getting the data but it would be much easier to separate the data and merge it together for a report total. Something like this (sorry for bad wrapping):

`| Black Chairs | Red Chairs | Beech Table | Black Table | Result                                                     |
|--------------|------------|-------------|-------------|------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3            | 0          | 0           | 1           | 3 Black Chairs, 1 Black Table                              |
| 0            | 2          | 1           | 0           | 2 Red Chairs, 1 Beech Table                                |
| 2            | 2          | 1           | 1           | 2 Black Chairs, 2 Red Chairs, 1 Beech Table, 1 Black Table |`